# Why sometimes there is no image on IMvxSideBar?

Tags: image, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross, hamburger-menu

I am using MvvmCross 4.4.0 and facing such problem: in some cases the hamburger icon and main page title do not appear for the side menu. (Watch image) In my case it isn't visible after showing menuViewModel right almost immediate App start. However, icon is visible when I navigate to other ViewModel before menuViewModel. Also it appears back after navigation to the some other page.

Code of the MenuView:

```
[MvxPanelPresentation(MvxPanelEnum.Left, MvxPanelHintType.ActivePanel, showPanel: false)]
public partial class MenuView : MvxViewController<MenuViewModel>, IMvxSidebarMenu
{
    public MenuView() : base("MenuView", null)
    {
    }

    public virtual bool HasShadowing => false;

    public UIImage MenuButtonImage => UIImage.FromBundle("HamburgerMenu");

....
}
```

Navigation from any page to this is always the same way

> ShowViewModel< MenuViewModel >();

Does anyone have any suggestion of workarounds? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: It is probably a bug that has been fixed in a newer version. You should consider upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is to hide and show NavigationBar in ViewWillAppear (maybe somewhere else too) method of the View that is main part of screen (Not sidebar).
I did it in such way:

```
 NavigationController.SetNavigationBarHidden(hidden: true, animated: false);
 NavigationController.SetNavigationBarHidden(hidden: false, animated: false);
```